# Move all Azure DevOps items from one user to another?

Tags: azure-devops, settings, user-accounts

We've had a guest user working in our DevOps team, but he's now a real team member with an Office 365 license assigned etc. In other words, he has a new user account. We'd like to migrate everything from his old account to his new one, including closed items. (And if at all possible, migrate his complete history).

Tried Google as well as a few searches here, but didn't find anything. I did find articles about migrating to a new organization, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean to move all the work items to be assigned to his new user? or also other things like permissions etc. ?

Comment: As much as possible, but permissions settings are pretty straightforward in our setup. It should suffice to just include the new user in our team. So, work items primarily.

Comment: Including comments on work items etc. if possible. We'd like to delete the old user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, If you just need to change the previous owner of the work items to the new account，you can write a query to find out all the work items assigned to the old account.
Then make a batch change to the query results and assign them to the new account.This operation preserves the history of previous work items

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Good idea. But there's no obvious way to move comment history from the old account to the new one?

Also, what will happen when we delete the old account? Will that account's comments be removed? Remain but no longer linked to any author?

Comment: @Kjell Through further testing, after changing the owner of the work items, the comment history still remains on the work item, even if the old account is removed from the organization, the comments left by the old account still exist.The author of the retained comments is the old account

Comment: Oh, so the old account is retained for historic reasons even if it's deleted from the user registry? Somewhat odd, but seems reasonable.